# Google login from flash Actionscript 2.0 in GAE

Tags: flash, google-app-engine, authentication, actionscript-2

I want to implement Google authentication in Flash (actionscript 2) in Google appengine. After pressing the login button it will redirect to the Google login page and will come back to the site after successful authentication. Also, it can logout in same way.

I am not good with actionscript and used "loadvers()" for action handling "onRelease" like functions.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You might look at something like [RPX](https://rpxnow.com/how_it_works) instead; they have some sample code after you "get" it. Generally you should be moving to AS3, and you'll have a lot more luck looking for AS3 samples on a site like http://www.kirupa.com/

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Yes, I found several implementations in AS3. But at this time one simple AS2 example would do fine.